# Receiving with permissions in broadcast receiver doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In android documentation(https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#receiving-broadcasts-permissions) it says:

> If you specify a permission parameter when registering a broadcast
>   receiver (either with registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver,
>   IntentFilter, String, Handler) or in  tag in your manifest),
>   then only broadcasters who have requested the permission with the
>    tag in their manifest (and subsequently been granted
>   the permission if it is dangerous) can send an Intent to the receiver.

But when i specify a *SEND_SMS* permission in receiver tag, the receiver still receives broadcasts, even though my app doesn't have *SEND_SMS* permission.

I registered receiver in Android manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Demo"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="demoFilter"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The demo class:

```
package com.android.wave;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Demo extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("Data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And i am sending the broadcast in my MainActivity's onCreate method:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("demoFilter").putExtra("Data", "some data"));
```

The permissions my app has:
[image]

When my mainActivity launches i get the toast message "some data". Which i shouldn't be getting since my app doesn't have the permission that the receiver needs.